# How to add an array item next to another array item when a specific value occurs

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sorting

Here I have a nested array that contains basic comment values

```
//cid is comment id and pid is parent id
$comments = array(
              array(
                'cid' = '47',
                'pid' = '0',
                'comment' = 'This is comment'
              ),
              array(
                'cid' = '48',
                'pid' = '0',
                'comment' = 'This is another comment'
              ),
              array(
                'cid' = '49',
                'pid' = '47',
                'comment' = 'This is child comment to parentID 47'
              ),
            );
```

What I want the end result is any comment array item that has a parentID should reposition itself right after that commentID which matches the parent ID. To visualise it the comment array which has a parent item is a reply to the original comment. So far I managed this much

```
//main loop
foreach ($comments as $index => $val) {

    $cids[] = $val['cid'];

    if($val['pid'] > 0) {
        foreach ($cids as $cidindex => $cid ) {

            if($val['pid'] == $cid) {
                $results[$index] = $val;
                $results[$index + 1] = _comment_load($cid, $array);
            }
        }
    } 
    else {
        $results_ano[$index] = $val;
    }
}//end of main loop

//loads comment
function _comment_load($cid, $array) {
    foreach ($array as $Key => $item) {
        if($item['cid'] == $cid) {
            return $item;
        }
    }
}
```

So after merging `$results` and `$results_ano` I get on `print_r`

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [pid] => 47
            [cid] => 49
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [pid] => 0
            [cid] => 47
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [pid] => 0
            [cid] => 47
        )

     [1] => Array
        (
            [pid] => 0
            [cid] => 48
        )
)
```

I did manage to get what I wanted slightly but, now the `commentId = 47` is repeating and I want the repeating `cid` item array to be removed from the resulting array.

Comment: Is there anything in particular that forces you to need that array in that particular order that cannot be achieved by multiple arrays?

Comment: Thank you, An array item which as a parent ID is a reply to a comment id which makes it a lot easier to template as well later on.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this by having the following after the 'main loop'

```
    foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
      foreach ($results_ano as $anokey => $anovalue) {
        if($anovalue['cid'] == $value['cid']) {
         //Ignore Everything in here
        }else {
            $finalresults[] = $anovalue;
        }
     }
   }

  $merge = $results = $finalresults;
```

which gives me an array without that repeating item.